# Does passing a method in C# to an parameter of type Action generate any garbage?

Tags: c#

Suppose we have this in .NET 5

```
using System;

public class ClassWithMethod
{
    public void MethodToCall() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private ClassWithMethod instance = new ClassWithMethod();
    
    private void Call(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }
    
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Call(instance.MethodToCall);
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Am I *guaranteed* that `Call(instance.MethodToCall);` will not create any object behind my back? The GC must not run here if I were to call that method millions of times.

Obviously `Program program = new Program();` and `private ClassWithMethod instance = new ClassWithMethod();` create two new objects, but there isn't some third one being brought into existence like the runtime inserting some anonymous function without my permission? As in, there is no extra object creation happening inside of the `DoStuff()` method?

Note that this is a strict requirement. I must not generate garbage whatsoever, or else bad things will happen.

The docs say that

> Delegates are similar to C++ function pointers, but delegates are fully object-oriented, and unlike C++ pointers to member functions, delegates encapsulate both an object instance and a method.

It is okay if the method and object get passed along, but I cannot be creating a whole new object in the process of doing so.

I believe this is passed to the delegate Action, but I cannot find any documentation which guarantees me that there's no magic happening which causes some object to come into existence and bite me later down the road.

For example, I used to pass around lambda's to functions and I hoped the VM would inline them and avoid object creation completely by being smart for me, but it didn't, and then I paid a terrible price for it later on and had to rewrite code. This was my fault since this is what one would expect by using lambdas in the way that I did, but the VM has been amazing in optimizations in the past so I figured it since it already does insane black magic optimizations that it could elide the object completely for me, of which I blame myself fully for this since I should not have made such assumptions, but this was the pain point that spurred this question.

Comment: `The GC must not run here` - it won't. It runs when it feels like, not when an object leaves a scope.

Comment: `it won't. It runs when it feels like, not when an object leaves a scope.` Let me reword what I am looking for: "When I create objects, the GC adds unacceptable undeterministic performance overhead, and when I do not create objects, this performance issue completely disappears. I must avoid this penalty at all costs due to its extremely debilitating results, and stopping object creation attains this." I figure this was something I didn't need to be pedantic about since I'd argue it's obvious what I mean, but there's the exact version.

Comment: @GSerg That link does not help me much because I don't know if that problem has been fixed or not. The C# team has done a lot of things (like static lambdas) which may possibly have resolved similar issues, meaning it's on their scope. I'll be moving to .NET 6 as well as soon as it comes out.

Comment: C# is all about the undeterministic performance overhead of the GC (which most programs never notice). This is not an "issue", it's a design choice, as opposed to the C++ approach. As the link explains, the optimization may or may not occur, you cannot rely on that. If you want to be sure, create an `Action` yourself and cache it.

Comment: @GSerg If it was all about that, then why would Microsoft be spending so much time implementing features trying to work around it? They even have added options to turn off the GC for parts of the code. I can't subscribe to the idea that C# is "all" about undeterministic performance, because that disagrees with the direction the language is being taken. Maybe it was a design choice in the past, but it doesn't seem to be one that is being adhered to very well looking at modern C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test this yourself by inspecting the generated IL with a tool like Linqpad or ILSpy.

Inside of Program.DoStuff, an allocation is created for the Action constructor:

```
IL_0000  nop   
IL_0001  ldarg.0   
IL_0002  ldarg.0   
IL_0003  ldfld  Program.instance 
IL_0008  ldftn  ClassWithMethod.MethodToCall () 
IL_000E  newobj  Action..ctor 
IL_0013  call  Program.Call (Action) 
IL_0018  nop   
IL_0019  ret
```

So yes, this will generate an object for the action inside of the DoStuff method.

Comment: So you're saying that if I look at IL with your proposed stuff, I am 100% guaranteed that it will never be more optimized than that? Like the runtime would never inline the method call ever and I am looking at the result that is maximally optimized?

Comment: No you’re absolutely not guaranteed but that wasn’t the premise of your question. Your concern was that it _could_ generate garbage and the answer is yes, most likely.